# Mount external USB drive as read-only, without root

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, usb

If I wish to visit someone and bring with me my phone, chromecast or miracast, and an external USB drive, to show pictures and home videos, I want to do that without risking clobbering up my external drive every time I do this. This happened to me last time, and I'm scared to do this again, because it took me days to restore that 4TB drive.
So, mounting the external drive as read only would be a solution. No more "fat" repairs on a PC after using it on an Android.
Is it possible to run a terminal and issue a "remount ro" command of sorts? Or perhaps there is an app for this? I haven't found one that does this.
My phone is not rooted and the only known root hack for my ECOO E04 is "kingroot" which apparently puts in place some unorthodox bits which you can't remove, so I haven't gone there.
I would *love* to ditch vfat in favor of ext4 though...