# Is it possible to use external hard drives with USB OTG?

Tags: usb, usb-on-the-go

On some sources I have read that it is impossible to use external hard drives over USB OTG.
Is it really impossible?
Isn't there some kind of workaround?
Update: Apparently ES file explorer can see the disk but can't open it. I heard there are such issues with NTFS hard drives on Android.

Comment: [Obviously it is possible](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/141485/16575), if your device supports it.

Comment: @Izzy You see the issue is I am not just tryin to connect any USB device, I am trying to connect an external hard drive. Those things require a lot of power. I have even tried connecting it, but so far no luck. The issue is usually that a phone can't give it enough power. But apparently if I connect the USB hub to a power source it should be enough. I have also tried that and still no luck.

Comment: I have never tried that. Just the linked question popped up earlier today and showed someone obviously uses this, so it's possible. So I thought I leave you a hint. Cannot say more on it – but I admit, you have your point with the power source (where a second USB connected to a power bank might be a way).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Absolutely possible, I do this almost every day. You need to have an otg dongle (not just a cable) that permits adding an external power source. I use a dongle I bought on amazon for £12 and normal usb battery pack. Then I can load films onto my phone from a 2tb WD passport.

Without the additional power source you are not able to read the drive as your phone (or tablet) can't output enough current to properly operate the HDD.

Comment: Actually,  my N7 2013 can power certain 2.5" drives, but you can guess what happens to my battery :)

Comment: Yeah, but it seems my phone can't read ntfs. And although I am a Linux user, I don't want to reformat my drive to ext4 because of compatibility with Windows PC's. I am trying to install ntfs support on my phone ATM.

Answer (score 2):

I read in several places that using hard drives with USB OTG was possible with Samsung Galaxy phones because Samsung reads NTFS-formatted drives. (I have an A9 Pro.)

But while I could use flash drives and micro-SD cards up to 200GB, I could not get NTFS-formatted external hard drive to work, with or without powered hubs.

Until...I prepared a WD Passport 2T drive, yes 2 terabyte.

How did I do it? I reformatted using exFAT. That's it. Then no powered hub, no lag, no overheating. No problems at all.